# Function failing half of the time

Tags: c, function

I have written a random path generator for my project and when it works it works as intended. However it only works sometimes.

In my main function I have a simple switch statement to call my three tasks for this     project.

```
while(Continue)
{

switch(Example_number)
    {
    default: printf("No such program exists.\n");
             break;
    case 1:  path();
             break;
    case 2:  Caesar_cipher();
             break;
    case 3:  anagram();
             break;
    }

    printf("Would you like to test another?(Y/N)\n");
    scanf("\n%c",&ch);
    if(ch == 'Y' || ch == 'y')
    {
        NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        Continue = false;
    }
}
```

When you input 1 it calls this function witch creates an array and calls the other two functions.

```
void path(void)
{
    //Creates the array walk.
    char walk[10][10] = {{'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                         {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                         {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                         {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                         {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                         {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                         {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                         {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                         {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'},
                         {'.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.','.'}};

//Creates a randomly generated path to travel along walk.
generate_path(walk);
print_array(walk);
}
```

The function that generates the path.

```
void generate_path(char walk[10][10])
{
int move_n = 0;
int row, column, i;
const char alph[] = {'B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'};
//Array that holds all previous data.
int move[3][25] = {0};
bool block = false;

//Allows for a random variable.
srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

row = rand() % 10;
column = rand() % 10;

while(!block)
{
    walk[row][column] = 'A';
    for(i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        //goto comes here
        restart:
        move_n = rand() % move_dir;
        //If space is open continue the alph array one row below.
        if(move_n == 0 && walk[row+1][column] == '.' && row+1 < 10)
        {
            row += 1;
            move[0][i] = i;
            move[1][i] = row;
            move[2][i] = column;
            walk[row][column] = alph[i];
        }
        else if(move_n == 1 && walk[row][column+1] == '.' && column+1 < 10) //If space is open continue the alph array one column to the right. 
        {
            column += 1;
            move[0][i] = i;
            move[1][i] = row;
            move[2][i] = column;
            walk[row][column] = alph[i];
        }
        else if(move_n == 2 && walk[row-1][column] == '.' && row-1 >= 0) //If space is open continue the alph array one row above.
        {
            row -= 1;
            move[0][i] = i;
            move[1][i] = row;
            move[2][i] = column;
            walk[row][column] = alph[i];
        }
        else if(move_n == 3 && walk[row][column-1] == '.' && column-1 >= 0) //If space is open continue the alph array one column to the left.      
        {
            column -= 1;
            move[0][i] = i;
            move[1][i] = row;
            move[2][i] = column;
            walk[row][column] = alph[i];
        }
        else if((walk[row][column-1] == '.') || (walk[row-1][column] == '.') || (walk[row][column+1] == '.') || (walk[row+1][column] == '.')) 
        {
            if(i == 25)
                break;
            goto restart;
        }
        else
        {
            //Resets data to point such that the path can continue.
            row = move[1][i-1];
            column = move[2][i-1];
            i--;
            walk[row][column] = '.';
        }
    }
    block = true;
}
}
```

And the print array function.

```
void print_array(char walk[10][10])
{
int i = 0;
int k = 0;
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    for(k = 0; k < 10; k++)
    {
        printf(" %c", walk[i][k]); 
    }
    printf("\n");
}
}
```

But for some reason upon inputting 1 into the switch statement it only works sometimes. Calling any other function works perfectly every time.

Comment: Where is the declaration for `Example_number`? Where do you assign it? Offtopic: you should stick to a naming convention, e.g. variables always start with lowercase. This will make your code more readable.

Comment: Aside: call `srand((unsigned) time(NULL));` only once per run, not every time you generate a new `path()`.

Comment: Are you sure that shouldn't be `scanf( "%c", &ch )`? why the newline?

Comment: @January To consume the newline that was left in the input buffer by the previous `scanf`. I'd prefer the format `" %c"`, however. (Any nonempty sequence of whitespace in a `scanf` format matches any sequence of whitespace in the input.)

Comment: Trevor, can you be more precise with "only works sometimes"? What happens when it doesn't work?

Comment: Out of interest, Why is this downvoted?

Comment: @DavidHughes if I were to guess I'd say because he doesn't describe how the program actually fails (e.g incorrect output vs. expected output, crashes, etc.) just that it doesn't work. Note I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: @DavidHughes: Probably because SO is not a debugging service... Compiling with warnings, running the code through a debugger and/or through Valgrind will help, a lot. Hell, in most cases answerers will probably do exactly that, something OP should have done in the first place. Also, http://sscce.org.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely your problem is with the `if` statements you have in generate_path().

You access `walk[row+1][column]`, `walk[row][column+1]` etc. `row` and `column` are generated with `rand()%10`. So `row` and `column` values *can be* `0` or `9` at some point and when accessing indexes`row-1` `column+1` etc,  it's going to access outside of the array bounds which can cause all sorts of problems.

Comment: It's declared outside of what I posted, and Daniel sometimes when I type 1 and hit enter it goes to a new line and sits.

I'm going to edit the rand row numbers and column numbers and see what that does.

Comment: @Trevor Ah, if it hangs, it's probably the last `else` with `i--;` in the `for`-loop. If you're unlucky, that can put you in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

A couple suggestions from a 30 year veteran of C programming...

1. Don't use keywords as variable names.  "Continue" will confuse other programmers because "continue" is a keyword.
2. I'd recommend making your boundary checks FIRST in the if stack in the path() function.  That way, if the boundary check fails, the other tests (including the out-of-bounds memory access) will not occur.
3. The "restart" path of the if stack in path() has **NO** boundary checks!

Lastly, I built a project from your code samples and I'm finding that it is getting "stuck" in the else branch of the if stack in path().  This appears to be happening because the outer loop counter (i) is decremented, row & column updated and then the loop iterates.  That causes i to be incremented and if the row/column that have been selected are also a point that cannot continue, the loop repeats infinitely.

--ammendment--

I've posted the program I built from your code samples at http://www.svalli.com/files/path.7z so that you may check to ensure I didn't alter your logic.  Here's the output I get (including some debug I added to show where/why the loop is hanging):

```
    Path -----------------------
     . . . . . . . . . .
     . . . . . F E . A .
     . . . I H G D C B .
     . . . J K . . . . .
     P O N M L . . . . .
     Q R S . . . . . . .
     . . T U . . . . . .
     . . . V . . . . . .
     . . X W . . . . . .
     . Z Y . . . . . . .
    Would you like to test another?(Y/N)
    y

    row 2/col 6
    Path -----------------------
     . . . . P O N M L K
     . . . . Q T U H I J
     . . . . R S . G . .
     . . . . . D E F . .
     . . . A B C . . . .
     . . . . . . . . . .
     . . . . . . . . . .
     . . . . . . . . . .
     . . . . . . . . . .
     . . . . . . . . . .
    Would you like to test another?(Y/N)
```

The second run would have hung forever trying to find a way out of cell 2,6 if my debug hadn't broken out when the hang was detected.  I hope this helps you track down the logic error -- I've not tried to understand your path algorithm, only to find where it is hanging and what the hang condition is.  Unless I drastically changed something (which I doubt) this is your problem.  I hope it helps.  Oh, if you find I've unintentially changed your logic, please show me how/where, OK?  I'd be interested to know that, too.

--more--

For anyone interested, I wrapped the path generator in a Win32 program so that it does one iteration every 1/2 second and updates the path on screen as it goes.  It draws the 'normal' path with red characters.  If it gets stuck, it draws the last character it checked in yellow and then, if it keeps getting stuck, it draws a plus sign in alternating yellow and green until it gets unstuck.  Picking Generate! from the menu will always start a new, clean path sequence and pressing Stop! will stop it when stuck (as will Generate! and, of course, exiting the program.)  You can get the executable here:  http://www.svalli.com/files/maze.7z  It is interesting to watch it work and easy to see why/how it gets stuck.  From this, I'm sure someone will figure out how to fix the path generator so that it never gets stuck.  Or perhaps the code I put in for debugging to detect the "stuck" condition is enough?  It just generated a short path that may not be possible to continue.

Comment: PS:  Here's another explanation of passing multidimensional arrays that might help, since it is using the same terms and array sizes you're using:  <http://www.taranets.net/cgi/ts/1.37/ts.ws.pl?w=329;b=284>  Good luck!

Comment: @KingsIndian:  At least his out-of-bounds access were all **reads**, which are typically a little bit less prone to errors.  Although, as system security improves that will be less and less true.  There was boundary checking in 4 of the 5 if() tests, but it should have been _before_ the tests that relied on the value being within bounds in order to take advantage of C's short-circuit && evaluation.

Comment: "You cannot pass a multi-dimensional array as a parameter like you are doing in C." Since you can't pass arrays at all in C, that has some technical truth in it. But the array expression is converted to a `char(*)[10]` when its name is given as the function argument, and that's the exact type these functions take. The prototype `void generate_path(char walk[10][10])` is exactly equivalent to `void generate_path(char walk[][10])` or, the exact type, `void generate_path(char (*walk)[10])`. There is no reason for the compiler to complain, and it works as intended.

Comment: @Daniel:  I stand corrected.  Your generate_path function will work with one and only one set of array dimensions.  That is not a normal case for subroutines, so it is not generally considered correct by programmers.  However, I hope that didn't stop you from looking at the last paragraph where I explained where and why your loop is getting stuck forever.

Comment: Steve, it's not my function or my loop. I endorse your suggestions, and agree with your diagnosis of the cause and hope the OP will read and follow.

Comment: &Daniel:  See my ammendment above.  I truly believe **is** your loop.  The path walk is sometimes generating a cul-de-sac and then walking into it with no way to back out.  Hopefully the example code I uploaded and/or the debug output will help explain what is happening.

Comment: It's not **my** loop, because it's not my question. Trevor asked it.

Comment: Shame on me.  I was looking so closely at the code I didn't see the names.  My apologies.

Comment: No problem, happens all the time here.

Comment: I hope Trevor comes back.  It was kinda fun looking into this!